# JavaScript 'contenteditable' -- Getting/Setting Caret Position

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have read a few posts on positioning the caret, but none seem to answer my particular issue.

1. I have 2 divs (**div1** and **div2**)
2. **div1** = noneditable div
3. **div2** = contenteditable div
4. both divs contain exact same contents
5. when user clicks on **div1**, it gets hidden, and **div2** appears in exact location and user can edit

**The problem**: I want the caret to appear in exact location on div2 as div1

So, I need some way to READ the location where the user clicks on div1, and then when div2 appears place the cursor/caret in that same location, so a **getCaretLocation(in_div_id)** and **setCaretLocation(in_div_id)** set of functions.

Any way to do that?

Thanks -

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem which makes me insane..

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer** : You can't

**Long answer** : The problem you'll face is that you'll be able to get (x,y) coordinates for the click event on div1, but any implementation of the caret position while require you knowing the position of the caret in the content (which is the number of characters preceding the caret).

To convert the (x,y) coordinates to a character position you actually need to know how many characters were before (ie. left on the current line and above, if the text is ltr).

If you use a fixed width font, you can simplify the problem : mapping an (x,y) coordinate to a (line, column) coordinate on a character grid.

However, you still face the problem of not knowing how the text is wrapped. For example :

```
------------------
|Lorem ipsum     |
|dolor sit amet  |
|consectetur     |
|adipiscing elit |
------------------
```

If the user clicks on the **d** in *dolor*, you know that the character is the 1st on the 2nd line, but without knowing the wrapping algorithm there is no way you'll know that it is the 13th character in "Lorem ipsum dolor sit…". And there is no guarantee that such a wrapping algorithm is identical across browsers and platform.

Now, what I'm wondering is why would you use 2 different synced `div` in the first place ? Wouldn't it be easier to use only one div and set its content to editable when the user clicks (or hovers) ?

Comment: using 2 divs because i am enabling user to DRAG div around, which interferes with SELECTING text (highlighting to make bold for example).

Comment: thinking maybe I can get coordinates and trigger click() event with same coordinates on div2 -- will try and see how it works.

Comment: @OneNerd: I'd lean toward a handle or something for the dragging, but without knowing what the rest of your UI is, I wouldn't know if that makes sense for what you're doing.

Comment: yeah - triggering a click at coordinates not working. voting your answer up since it is thorough and helps. thanks -

Comment: This question is very much related to one of my questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006623/drag-n-drop-on-contenteditable-elements). It would probably have been easier if one could successfully "simulate" a click on the contenteditable div using the coordinates of the original click. I have tried the jquery.simulate plugin but it did not seem to work at all, perhaps because it is not compatible with jQuery 1.6 (the plugin was last updated in 2009). Once I can get it working or find a suitable solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a tiny span-element at the caret, get its position, and remove it. For a cross-browser range and selection library, see [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).

Comment: +1 for rangy. Trying to deal with ranges on your own is a disaster

Answer (score 1):

you can, basically you need set temporary content editable on your first div to catch caret pos

```
$('div1').hover(function()
{ $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
},function()
{ $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
}).mouseup(function()
{   var t = $(this);
    // get caret position and remove content editable
    var caret = t.getCaret();
    t.removeAttr('contenteditable');
    // do your div switch stuff
    ...
    // and apply saved caret position
    $('div2').setCaret(caret);
});
```

now just need get/set caret method :)

edit > here is my own, ([live demo](http://r043v.github.com/jQuery.scribe/))

```
        getSelection:function($e)
        {   if(undefined === window.getSelection) return false;
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

            function getTreeOffset($root,$node)
            {   if($node.parents($root).length === 0) return false; // is node child of root ?
                var tree = [], treesize = 0;
                while(1)
                {   if($node.is($root)) break;
                    var index, $parent = $node.parent();
                    index = $parent.contents().index($node);
                    if(index !== -1) { tree[treesize++] = index; } $node = $parent;
                };  return tree.reverse();
            }

            var start = getTreeOffset($e,$(range.startContainer));
            var end   = getTreeOffset($e,$(range.endContainer));

            if(start & end === false) return false;

            return {start:start,end:end,startOffset:range.startOffset,endOffset:range.endOffset};
        }, setSelection:function($e,s,win)
        {   $e.focus(); if(s === false) return; var sel = win.getSelection(); sel.removeAllRanges();

            function getNode($e,s)
            {   var node = $e;
                for( var n=0;n<s.length;n++ )
                {   var index = s[n]; if(index < 0) break;
                    node = node.contents(':eq('+index+')');
                }   return node.get(0);
            }

            var start = getNode($e,s.start), end = getNode($e,s.end), range = win.document.createRange();
            range.setStart(start,s.startOffset); range.setEnd(end,s.endOffset); sel.addRange(range);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do an inline edit... have you looked at the [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an element, a Selection object with zero length is created (get it from element.getSelection() , where element is the div in question). The focusOffset of that object will let you know that you clicked on, for example, the 74th character in that div (this is the thing that Adrien said was impossible in a different answer).