# How to propagate event? InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I'm trying to propagate an event from my `window.document` to an iframe within this document.

When catching the event in the `window.document` I try the following:

```
event.preventDefault()
(@dispatchTo()).dispatchEvent(event)
# @dispatchTo() returns the reference of `document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument`
```

But I get `InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.`

I tried `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` but none would work. It seems that the event is being dispatched while I try to dispatch it to the iframe document and it fails.

How can I propagate an event to my iframe while catching it from the `window.document`?

I do have another eventListener on the iframe for that event, but it doesn't get triggered.

I use React (which has a *virtual DOM*, it may interfere, it may not, just saying).

---

I found part-of-a-solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20541207/2391795

And now I'm able to dispatch events from the document to the iframe using this code:

```
eventClone = new event.constructor(event.type, event)
(@dispatchTo()).dispatchEvent(eventClone)
```

But since I'm using React, the cloned event isn't equal to the initial event, because React has a kind-of wrapper for events. So I loose many properties, like the `which` and `isTrusted`, which become `false` once cloned.

Is there any way to properly clone a React event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or re-dispatch DOM events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974262/how-to-clone-or-re-dispatch-dom-events)

Comment: `isTrusted` is not part of React, it's a native browser event property. You cannot programmatically create an event and have isTrusted be `true`.

Answer (score 14):

Some event property values disappear when you try to copy the event. That's because many of the event properties have their enumerable property set to false:

```
Object.defineProperty(event, "target", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
});
```

That prevents the value of the property from being copied when you clone the event. If you tried `Object.keys(evt)`, the only key that gets returned is `isTrusted`.

Some properties like target and path only get set after the event is dispatched, and you cannot assign them manually. So if you try to dispatch an event that already has a target, you will hit the error `InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched`.

That's why you hit this error. You tried to dispatch an event that already got dispatched instead of dispatching a new event.

So when you create your event, you should only copy the properties you care about:

```
 eventClone = new event.constructor(event.type, propertiesICareAbout)
```

where `propertiesICareAbout` is an object containing the parts of the event you care about, for example `propertiesICareAbout = {shiftKey: event.shiftKey}`

`isTrusted` is a property with a specific purpose-- return `false` if a script has interacted with the event. The property is set to `false` for exactly that reason. You are using a script to interact with the event and dispatching it via a script. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

The `which` property is deprecated and in the process of being dropped, so you shouldn't use that anyway.

React events are probably unrelated to your question. The React synthetic event is delegated and pooled at the top level for performance reasons. If you are dispatching events manually, you should use the native browser method `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: Nice answer. I want to set `isTrusted` to true when it's false beforehand. Not sure how.

Comment: You can't. That's the point of isTrusted.