# How can I click on specific (x,y) coordinates on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, coordinates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Triggering a JavaScript click() event at specific coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates)

**Translated question:**
I'm looking for a method to programmatically click on a specific (x,y) coordinate on a web page.

**Original question:**
I have reviewed many codes in the internet about how to let the pointer mouse move and click but I did not find what I need example: there is a hyper link on (X=358,Y=13) of the page and it is get different every time you get visited the page I want any code html or PHP or JavaScript that I can put it through web page that let the cursor just click on that link that is on the coordination x,y and I need it to execute the command just when the some one open the web page don't tell me that I want redirection to specify URL no I said (it is get different every time you get visited) I just want click on specify coordination no matter who is URL.

Comment: Could you at least read the question over once before posting it? Just *one* read through, to catch the worst of the typos and such? ("throgh cordnition"?!?! It's fine not to be a native English speaker, totally fine. But this is rubbish.)

Comment: This question is incomprehensible to me. Also, if you're worrying about particular coordinates you're either trying to clickjack or you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'd edit the question to make it more clear but I can't even begin to understand it, no less clean it up.

Comment: Hey, take some of these `.,..; ,, ;..,.  . ` I don't need them now. I'm not english mothertongue but I see I'm not the only one at loss here..

Comment: I guess you want that, when a user loads your page, his mouse pointer gets redirected to the coordinates you specify, and automatically click the link, no matter what it leads to?

Comment: My brain hurts.. but I think I understand what he wants: Use JavaScript to programmatically click on specific (x,y) coordinates within the web page.

Comment: Let me make the question more clear: "How can I make the visitor click my ads automatically?" This is basically what the poster asks about.

Comment: "hi i have reviewed many codes in the internet" - i have found my new SO bio.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, what you are trying to do isn't possible, because browsers specifically prevent you from doing this (for good security reasons).