# Set up a click event using mouse position in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Can anyone tell me how I can assign a click function to particular coordinates within an element?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates

Comment: not a duplicate - If I understand him correctly, the OP wants to _register_ a handler for a particular location, not fake an event.

Comment: with what granularity - a rectangle, a single pixel, something else?

Comment: yeah, just a small rectangle needs to be clickable, i can't use an element because it would interfere with other functionality i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var top = 0,
        right = 200,
        bottom = 200,
        left = 0;


    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;
    if ((x >= left && x <= right) && (y >= top && y <= bottom))
    {
        // do stuff if within the rectangle
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be working ok, but is there a way to easily define a small width and height of the clickable area ?
Any chance of some help on defining where the clickable area is ?

Comment: You could use Jquery's $(...).offset() method to grab the absolute x and y of your element.

so like left = $(elm).offset().left, top = $(elm).offset().top; and then add the width & height you want for the other sides of the bounding box.

Comment: Would that be the if statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gYkXS/3/

Hope this helps, have a nice one! cheers!

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#foo").mousemove(function(e){
      window.xPos = e.pageX;
      window.yPos = e.pageY;
       alert("Position X = " + e.pageX + "Position y = " + e.pageY);
   }); 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want part of the element to respond to a click (which is how I read your question), you can do that by looking at where the click happened.

Example: [live copy](http://jsbin.com/ozomag) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ozomag/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#target").click(function(event) {
      var $this = $(this),
          width = $this.width(),
          pos = $this.offset(),
          x = event.pageX - pos.left,
          y = event.pageY - pos.top;

      display("Click was at (" + x + "," + y + ") in the element");
      if (x > (width / 2)) {
          display("Clicked in the right half");
      }
  });


  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

`event.pageX` and `event.pageY` are document coordinates, which are what the [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) function gives you for the element. (Despite the name, `offset` does not give you the offset relative to the element's offset parent; that's `position`. Strange but true.) So you can translate `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` to element coordinates by simply subtracting `pos.left` from `event.pageX` and `pos.top` from `event.pageY`.

Answer (score 0):

Every event in jquery has `pageX` and `pageY` properties. So if you fire an event, you can check the coordinates:

```
$('#elem').click(function(e)) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    if (x > x1 && x < x2 && y > y1 && y < y2) {
         do_something
    }
}
```

In this case `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` are the coordinates of rectangle.

`pageX`, `pageY` are the page coordinates, if you need the relative ones within an element you need to get position of the element on the page then calculate the real coords basing on the element position.

Answer (score 0):

Live example http://jsfiddle.net/LBKTe/1

Basically same thing as AlecTMH described above.

```
// top left and botom right corners of the clickable area
var x1 = 10, x2 = 30, y1 = 10, y2 = 30;
$(document).on('click', '#block', function(e) {
    // get x/y coordinates inside    
    var cx = e.clientX;
    var cy = e.clientY;
    offset = $(this).offset();
    x = cx-offset.left;
    y = cy-offset.top;

    // if our click coordinates are within constrains, show an alert
    if (x >= x1 && x <= x2 && y >= y1 && y <= y2) {
      alert('click!');            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only a small number of "areas of interest" you can avoid capturing mouse clicks on the entire element by superimposing one or more empty elements of the required size with a `position: absolute` style and a high `z-index`, i.e.:

```
.hotspot {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

div {
    position: relative;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
​
<div class="frame">
    <canvas width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
    <div class="hotspot" style="left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 40px; height: 40px">
    </div>
</div>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/VUx2G/2/

Comment: Unfortunately i need there to be no element for the click function otherwise it disrupts other functionality, thanks for the help though.