# How do click specific coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, coordinates

I need to use jQuery (or anything) that clicked specific coordinates after button is clicked.
[image: specific coordinates]

Here is my code, but It not working. As you see in picture in these coordinates (10,15) is red button, which should be clicked.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#filter").click(function(e){
             //If I add alert here It successfully print message.
             var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
                e.pageX = 10;
                e.pageY = 15;
                $("#elem").trigger(e);
        });
    });
    </script>

<input type="button" id="filter" name="filter" value="Filter" />
```

I've read this, but wont help: [Triggering a JavaScript click() event at specific coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates)

Comment: For IE you might have to use AttachEvent.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically trying to do is to `trigger click on some other button` , `based on the click of this button`.

you should try something like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#filter").click(function(e){
           $('#redbuttonID').trigger('click');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

the rest of the code for setting `e.pageX` etc is not required

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/J9v6z/

EDIT:

you can get an element using x/y co-ordinates - so you could fire a click event on the element at x/y.

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
```

or

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).trigger('click');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.elementFromPoint

EDIT: updated fiddle with your requirement:

http://jsfiddle.net/J9v6z/1/

Comment: Thank you for answer, here `$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).trigger('click');` instead x, y I need to enter number of coordinates?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė see the last edit, it addresses your requirement exactly

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė did you check the link at the last. i have a working code there http://jsfiddle.net/J9v6z/1/

Comment: I'm trying to click Facebook button by this way, maybe that's why It not working

Comment: are you sure you have got the correct coordinates? does the fiddle work well for you?

Comment: Yes, fiddle working and coordinates are correct, so that problem is because It can't click Facebook like button I think.