# Awesomium WebControl Clicking/Writing

Tags: awesomium

I am trying to let click/write on the Awesomium WebControl, but it doesn't work.
This is the code that I use:

```
WebControl1.Source = New Uri("website") 'i dont put the website
xpath=link.xpath
Dim nlink As JSObject = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult([String].Format("document.evaluate(""{0}"", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue", xpath))

nlink.InvokeAsync("click")
end if
next
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i dont put the website" ? What do you expect to see in `WebControl1` then ?

Comment: I censored the website just for privacy

Comment: Oh, ok. That'd make sense. Just to be sure, You want to trigger `click` on your website loaded in `WebControl1` ? @dijamenh

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just trigger 'click' on your website content, that should work (using jQuery):

```
WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript(@"$(document.body).trigger('click');");
```

or (I've found it [here](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/829/invokememberclick.html), not tested):

```
        dynamic document = (JSObject)webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");

        if (document == null)
            return;

        using (document)
        {
            dynamic signin = document.getElementById("signin");

            if (signin == null)
                return;

            using (signin)
                signin.click();
        }
```

Remember to wait till DocumentReady is Loaded state:

```
    private void BaseWebControl_DocumentReady(object sender, DocumentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ReadyState != DocumentReadyState.Loaded) return;

        // Now! 
    }
```

EDIT:

```
<a id="foo" href="http://...." target="_blank">Test link</a>
```

in jQuery:

```
jQuery('#foo')[0].click();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying, but I would write to the webcontrol1, too

Comment: I would to click with an ID on page, what shoud i do?

Comment: Do you want to simulate `click` on specific DOM object? @dijamenh

Comment: @dijamenh I added EDIT to my answer

Comment: I must click by coordinates X,Y and write to the document, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand you. What is " to write too on the document"? 

I just showed you how to run script via Awesomium, you can use jQuery. I showed you how to simulate click on DOM object. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates) you can find how to click on  X,Y coordinates.

Comment: Sorry but I would make it on vb.net, a solution? Btw, I have a flash game, with childforms that are made in run-time and runned in run-time, I would click on the center of the screen of awesomium and write from the textbox1. Should I use sendkeys.send?

Comment: I think you got the idea reading c#. For more information read [this](http://wiki.awesomium.net) carefully. If you have other question, ask new, separate one

Comment: On my question i said "and how to write on the document? should i use sendkeys?".

Comment: @dijamenh I don't know that. I'm not even sure what do you mean by "write on the document". But have you tried yourself?

Comment: No, I would do that but I add childforms, that contains each awesomium webcontrol,  by memory, in run-time, so i don't even know how to manage them.

Comment: You have to read awesomium tutorial, docs, something, because I can't show you how to manage app build on awesomium webcontrols here. It will be much easier for you then. I hope I helped you at least with trigger 'click'