# make mouse position with js code and put the position in other js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

**i have a auto clicker that work with mouse position** . here is the code :

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint( x,y );

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked')
}, false);

var support = true;

try {
    if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false}).bubbles !== false) {
        support = false;
    } else if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}).bubbles !== true) {
        support = false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    support = false;
}

setInterval(function() {
    if (support) {
        var event = new MouseEvent('click');
    }else{
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    }
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
},1000);
```

and i also have code for get mouse position :

```
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
}
setInterval("checkCursor()", 1000);
function checkCursor(){
   alert( cursorX + ","+ cursorY);
}
```

**and my questions is : how can i put mouse position in document.elementFromPoint(x,y ) ????**

*i know can put my x and y but i want to x and y update when i move mouse anywhere*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triggering a JavaScript click() event at specific coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates)

Comment: i know can put my x and y but i want to x and y update when i move mouse anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

You actually need to initialize `elem` and `cursorX` and `cursorY` first, sorry, didn't test this code.

Declare elem as a variable
`var elem = document.elementFromPoint( cursorX,cursorY );`

And initialize cursors `cursorX = 0; cursorY = 0`

Then inside your mousemove function, do this

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
   cursorX = e.pageX;
   cursorY = e.pageY;
   elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
}
```