# Click on x/y point of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I simulate a click on `x`/`y` coords on the `stats_wrapper`?

```
<div class="stats_wrapper">
    <span class="like_icon"></span>
    <span class="number_of_likes">
        10
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the x/y-coords of the click happend or do you just need this element programmatically clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate a click (X/Y coords.)"? Why would you need that? What is your expected result? Isn't this HTML wrapped in a iframe (cross domain)/third party plugin?

Comment: Everyone would appreciate if you share the user case

Comment: I need to click the : like_icon by using coordinates or click: like_icon  only inside the div named: stats_wrapper . I'm not allowed to use if statements  , quite a challenge

Answer (score 1):

Set the pageX and pageY properties (which are normalized) on the event object and pass it to .trigger(), like this:

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
e.pageX = 10;
e.pageY = 10;
$("#elem").trigger(e);
```

Cited form [Triggering a JavaScript click() event at specific coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845178/triggering-a-javascript-click-event-at-specific-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to go with X/Y coordinates?

If I were you, I'd use the event dispatcher.

```
var down = new MouseEvent('mousedown') 
var up = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("stats_wrapper")[0];
elem.dispatchEvent(down);
elem.dispatchEvent(up);
```

That way, you tell your div that it was clicked and you do not need to worry about coordinates. 
Obviously, I don't know your use case so it might not be what your looking for.

Edit: This is a pure JS solution. For a JQuery solution, you should use `$(.stats_wrapper).trigger('click')` as mentionned by Velimir

Answer (score -1):

To simulate a click on `.stats_wrapper` you can use this (jQuery):
`$(.stats_wrapper).trigger("click");`
You can also click any element inside it instead, I see no function of triggering a click on a specific pixel within a single element