# Drag block element from one point to another inside ContentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

I'm needing to let users drag an element inside a contenteditable div to another point in the text.  The item that needs to be movable is set to ContentEditable=false.

Is this possible?  I can't seem to find any real solutions.  Here's what I want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/s82Ex/

Comment: Are you using a webkit browser? Those are the buggiest ones with regards to several contentEditable features like this one

Comment: I am, and Webkit, followed by Mozilla would be my target audience.  I'll probably completely drop support for IE.

Comment: I this a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3006623/1048572?

Answer (score 6):

### ***UPDATE 10/11/2016***

> **demo & source:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/drag-block-element-from-one-point-to-another-inside-contenteditable-div

i have updated the code to use the latest jquery and jquery-ui and refactored it, so it can be implemented in a plugin in future and fixed various bugs:

now it take in consideration also text with punctuation and extra spaces in it like this:

```
lorem,ipsum
lorem    ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem.ipsum
```

keep in mind this is still a proof of concept...

Comment: This will be a GREAT piece of code to build from.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answers from credible and official sources: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12250

Comment: Hmm ok.  The solution I ended up using was jQuery UI Sortable.  May not work for everyone, but in my case it worked perfectly.