# jqueryui drag image into a contentEditable div and drop it at that position within the text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

I have a image that is a jqueryui draggable and a div that is a jqueryui droppable that contains text / html and is contentEditable=true.

I want to be able to drag the image over the contentEditable text and when i drop it i want to be able to drop the image at that text / character position.

I have found many ways to do this if i click or select text in the editable then drag the image in using the selected text range but when i just drag the image and drop it there is no text selected.

How can i set the selected / cursor position in the contentEditable text on drop event ?

anyone help with this ?

thank you
Rick

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what the problem is.

Comment: hi Tim    i have used your code in this http://jsfiddle.net/rmossuk/qLQtK/2/ to get the cursor position when i drop the image onto the contentEditable.      But this only works if i first click inside the contentEditable then drag the image into it.    What i want to do is not have to click or select text in the contentEditable but just drag the image in and on drop, i want to get the position of my mouse in the text, so that i can then add the image code to that postion in the text.      Hope this makes sense ???    Can you help ?   thanks a lot

Comment: This appears to have been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006623/drag-n-drop-on-contenteditable-elements - though I don't like that answer much, and am still looking.

Comment: I've found a more satisfactory answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678451/precise-drag-and-drop-within-a-contenteditable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654262/drop-image-into-contenteditable-in-chrome-to-the-cursor

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered elsewhere on this site: [Precise Drag and Drop within a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678451/precise-drag-and-drop-within-a-contenteditable)

The solution there has code specific to each browser (via feature detection), and currently only works in Chrome and Firefox.  For Chrome, a range needs to be computed from the mouse coordinates using `document.caretRangeFromPoint`.  For Firefox, the event object has the `rangeParent` and `rangeOffset` properties, which can be used to determine where the caret should be positioned.

```
document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    var sel = document.getSelection();
    if(document.caretRangeFromPoint) { // Chrome
        var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if(e.rangeParent) { // Firefox
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(e.rangeParent, e.rangeOffset);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if(sel.rangeCount == 0) { // Default to at least not completely failing
        var range = document.createRange();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }

    // The selection is now in the right place - proceed with whatever the drop should do
});
```

This code is designed to work with the entire document being editable - for an editable div, you'll need to set the event listener on that div, and modify the fallback case to guarantee that the selection is inside the div.