# How to move/drag table that generated using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, drag-and-drop, ckeditor, draggable

I have the following code that generated from Javascript code "CKEditor".

The Code:

```
<table border="2" id="table001">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="td001"><img alt="" src="http://localhost:8888/xxx/ckeditor/ckfinder/userfiles/images/hh.png" style="height:400px; width:400px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><em>This is the caption.</em></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to know how can I make it draggable in the text area as 1 unit? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop in CKEditor utilizes native browser implementation. If any. It means that you can drag images, tables and stuff only if the browser you use actually supports that. It works pretty cool in IE, but Firefox and Chrome will let you drag and drop if you select some table cells first. This has pretty much nothing to do with CKEditor.

There were [several attempts](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html) to standardize D&D (dungeons & dragons :b) in browsers (not necessarily in contenteditable) but still this is nothing like a good implementation. You might also be interested in this question: [Precise Drag and Drop within a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678451/precise-drag-and-drop-within-a-contenteditable)

I'm sorry to say that but most likely you got to create an excessive amounts of code to have something that might not works as desired.